# Manhwa about a daughter who offers to reincarnate her mother to before she was born

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, reincarnation

The daughter and the mother are talking to one another while having tea. The mother brings up how talented she is in magic, because women in this world rarely have magic power. The daughter brings up that she learned how to reincarnate with her magic and offers to reincarnate her mother instead of her.

Comment: Is the answer submitted below correct? If it is, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Or if it's incorrect, please leave a comment beneath it indicating that, so that we know to keep looking.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[My Dear Aster](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-dear-aster)***...?

> A few years ago, Lihen’s daughter said, “If mother ever lives again, don’t give birth to me.” “What are you talking about all of a sudden?” “You don’t have to give birth to me. Meet someone better than Dad. You said you had a first love. If you live again, confess. Who knows? Maybe it will work out?” The mother and daughter giggled together. Then Lihen Copland woke up. As a nineteen-year-old. Living again didn’t change her life much. But maybe she could make her daughter a little happier. To do so, she would have to marry her husband again. But that resolve soon began to waver. After meeting her first love, Sir Schudermel Laft.

There's a scene in the first chapter matching your description, where a mother and daughter are sitting and chatting whilst drinking tea, and the daughter says that if she ever got the chance to regress -- i.e. to go back in time and relive her life -- she'd give it to her mother. The daughter also mentions that she's a wizard.

[image]